# expression must have a constant value error in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to initialize an array with non-constant variables? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972705/is-there-a-way-to-initialize-an-array-with-non-constant-variables-c)

I have the following code:

```
vector<vector<vec2>> vinciP;
    int myLines = -1;
    myLines = drawPolyLineFile("vinci.dat", vinciP);
    if (myLines > -1)
    {
        cout << "\n\nSUCCESS";
        vec2 vPoints[myLines];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumPoints; ++i)
        {
            vPoints[i] = vinciP[0][i];
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error on the line 'vec2 vPoints[myLines];' that says expressions must have a constant value. I don't understand why I'm getting this error, any help?

Is it because myLines could be negative? idk.

Comment: `vector<vector<vec2>> vinciP` may not compile in VC++. For portability, a better practice would be `vector<vector<vec2> > vinciP`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
vec2 vPoints[myLines];
```

Since `myLines` is not a *const* expression ((which means, it is not known at compile-time), so the above code declares a variable length array which is not allowed in C++. Only C99 has this feature. Your compiler might have this as an extension (but that is not Standard C++).

The solution to such commom problem is  : use `std::vector<T>` as:

```
std::vector<vec2> vPoints(myLines);
```

It should work now.

Comment: GCC has this available as an extension in c++ mode. It is surprising to me this feature hasn't managed its way into c++.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: VLA were introduced in C99, C++ was based on C98, and by the time C99 introduced VLA, C++ already had vector, so they never felt a need of pressing for it.

Comment: @Als, I was not aware that "C++ was based on C98", I'm assuming you are referring to 0x, maybe I should create a separate question for this, but the existence of std::vector does not really convince me of the non-usefulness of VLAs.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Indeed the usefulness `VLA` can provide in C++ are manyfold but it seems there is too much work to get it done to get those to work in C++. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c/1887178#1887178) is a thread that discusses this.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: No need to create another topic: Someone has already created this. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458857/why-doesnt-c-support-dynamic-arrays-on-the-stack

Comment: @Als, Very relevant thread, thanks. JS - litb to the rescue once again, no further ?'s on my part. I would make a few counter-arguments Nawas on your reply, but combined I'm good.

Comment: C98 above is a typo. C++ was based on C89. C++11 has adopted some features of C99 but not VLAs. VLAs will probably never be in C++. Consider 'void foo(int (&arr)[10]);' In C++ the size of an array is part of its type and is used in type checking, and VLAs simply cannot work this way.

Comment: @barnes Yes (C89 of course =) the links provided makes these non-C complexities quite clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Is it because myLines could be negative?**
No, It is because `myLines` is not a compile time constant.

**Explanation:**

```
vec2 vPoints[myLines];
```

Creates an array of variable length, where `myLines` value will be determined at Run-time.
**[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)** are not allowed in C++.  It was a feature introduced in C99, and C++ Standard does not support it. Some C++ compilers support it as an extension though but it is nevertheless non standard conforming.

For C++ size of an array should be known at compile time and hence must be compile time constant. `myLines` is not a compile time constant and hence the error.

You should use a **std::vector**

Answer (score 1):

```
vec2 vPoints[myLines];
```

Array size **must** be a compile time constant. `myLines` is not a compile time constant. Instead, allocate the memory using **new** or even better to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Using `new` is wrong! Never use `new`, learn to program without `new`. There is no need of `new` here!

Comment: +1 I know `new` is `old` for C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have variable-length arrays. The size of an array *must* be determined at compile-time. The value of `myLines` is only known at runtime, so this won't work.

To have arrays whose size is only known at runtime, use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<vec2> vPoints(myLines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because static arrays need a static (constant) size. Since the number of components in your `vPoints` is dynamic, consider using a dynamic array instead. Or better yet stick with `vector`.