# File stream, STL container, and variable length arrays

Tags: c++, stl, ofstream

Originally, I have some code that looks like

```
class Ball
{
public:
    double x , y ;
    ofstream out ;
} ;

int main()
{
    Ball array[N] ;

    array[0].out.open("./position_1.txt") ;
    array[1].out.open("./position_2.txt") ;

    ......
}
```

where N is a run-time determined constant.
But it suffers variable length arrays problem recently.

I try to follow the suggestion by this post [Can't set variable length with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045266/cant-set-variable-length-with-variable) by using STL container.

```
int main()
{
    vector<Ball> Balls ;
    Ball b ;

    b.out.open( "./position_1.txt" ) ;
    Balls.push_back( b ) ;
    ......
}
```

It fails at `push_bak()`, since stream can not be copied.

I can't determine the number of balls before running and I have to store the file stream instead of path for efficiency (preventing opening and closing files).

Is there any way to achieve the goal? 
Thanks

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to achieve? Load a variable count of ball coordinates from a single file?

Comment: Yes, I have many images of balls and each image has many balls.

Comment: I have many images and each image has many balls.
The ball numbers is fixed for each movie, but it is determined after first identification. I want to track them, 1, 2,.. and save them to 1.txt, 2.txt,..So I keep the file stream for each one for easy access and efficiency. 

Now, I maintain/new an array of streams outside the class and change "ofstream out" to be "ofstream *out"...Similar to the suggestions below. Thanks for your suggestion. 

But I wounder if there is a more "nature" way like the suggestion of using C++11. But, my gcc is not support C++11. I can't check so far. still thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ streams are not copyable, but they're movable, so you can do this instead:

```
Balls.push_back( std::move(b) );

//DO NOT use b after push_back, as it has been moved!
```

and the default move-semantic generated by compiler for your class will work fine with this.

In C++11, you can write this:

```
std::vector<Ball> balls(N); //N is known at runtime

balls[i].out.open( "./position_1.txt" ); //i <= i < N
```

Note that this will not work in C++03, as in C++03 vector's constructor creates N *copies* of a default created object of type `Ball`. In C++11, however, it doesn't make any copy!

Comment: Or, since there is hardly ever a reason to use `open` or `close` on a `std::stream`, `balls.emplace_back("./position_1.txt")`, which would require a reasonable `Ball` constructor, though.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler/library are old enough that they don't support move semantics for streams yet (many don't) you might consider storing a (smart) pointer to a stream in the structure instead. You do probably want it to be a smart pointer though -- handling ownership transfer correctly on your own is likely to be quite a bit of work to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Then make Balls a vector of pointers to Ball. Allocate the Ball objects with new and push_back the pointers.

Note that, if you use simple pointers, you must delete the Ball objects at the end with a loop. You can avoid this by using smart pointers, like `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.